# Upload via gettyimages api

Tags: api, image-uploading

Is there any way to upload photos to gettyimages?
They don't have it in the API (https://api.gettyimages.com/de/apis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear so. From [here](http://contributors.gettyimages.com/article_public.aspx?article_id=2371) (emphasis mine):

> For 35mm digital capture, we strongly recommend use of a professional-quality digital SLR using **RAW or uncompressed TIFF format**.

RAW or uncompressed TIFF images will tend to be very large, which could make uploading them via an API problematic. Instead, contributors would use the [upload portal](https://upload.gettyimages.com/) to supply content to Getty images.

Further, your images must go through a [submission process](http://contributors.gettyimages.com/article_public.aspx?article_id=2373), which would suggest the API could not be used.

Getty Images do have a [Flickr collection](http://www.gettyimages.co.nz/Creative/Frontdoor/FlickrPhotos) that anyone can submit to, though once again there is [submission process](http://www.gettyimages.com/creative/frontdoor/contributors).